# nginx alias not working for static files folder

Tags: django, nginx

I don't know why nginx alias is not working.

Why this line doesn't work:

```
location /static/  {
            alias /home/django11/example.com/finansuinfo/static_root/;
        }
```

Actually maybe it is working but my admin page static files isn't served. I get error that static/admin/... doesn't exist.

I guess it only serves files in static folder but not in static_root folder where all files are collected by manage.py collectstatic

Here is my config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /home/django11/example.com/example;

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django11/example.com/example/example.sock;
}

location /static/  {
    alias /home/django11/example.com/example/static_root/;
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js|woff)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

}

I found out that alias doesn't work because of:

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js|woff)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions how to fix it? Because when I remove this static_root works.

Comment: What values do you have for STATUC_URL and STATIC_ROOT variables?
did you check directory ownership?

Comment: this is my settings.py file and what you mean check directory ownership?
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

Comment: The static files you are trying to access, are those one of the file extensions you have used in the later location configs e.g. css, js  or media files?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation of [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) config in nginx:

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching). **To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations)**. Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. **Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.**

The case in your question can be explained from this:

When you try to access a static file (which I guess is one of css, js or media files), it first matched the **prefix string**:

```
location /static/  {
    alias /home/django11/example.com/example/static_root/;
}
```

Then, it start searching for regular expressions, and in case of a css or js file following will get a match:

```
# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js|woff)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Where the search terminated and the above config is used. And, in this config alias is not defined so no alias is used.

When you remove this regular expression location block, then the config from the prefix location is used. And, since that includes alias, it works.

Comment: Maybe you know how to make alias work with expires header?